Why use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to prove Ax–Grothendieck theorem?
Hi I have a question about the prove of Ax–Grothendieck theorem and it actually uses Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to prove that polynomial mapping for algebraic closure of limited field, if the mapping is injection then it's bijection.

If $F$ is a finite field, then $F^n$ is finite. In this case the theorem is true for trivial reasons having nothing to do with the representation of the function as a polynomial: any injection of a finite set to itself is a bijection. When F is the algebraic closure of a finite field, the result follows from Hilbert's Nullstellensatz.

My question is why we need Hilbert's Nullstellensatz to prove this, I tried to explain in this post that it seems to me that we do not need the Nullstellensatz to prove it.
Is that true or there are mistakes I did not realize in my prove??

Seems to be a duplicate of your previous question?

@martinbrandenburg yep but my last question focus on the connection between Nullstellensatz and the proof. This question is focusing on why I need Nullstellensatz

So, the same question then :)

@martinbrandenburg I don't know, if I say my first question is why Nullstellensatz can prove the result, and second is would that be true of proving the result do not need Nullstellensatz, then are they the same or not.....
